# Textarea element doesn't return any value with POST

Tags: php, html

I'm trying get the value from textarea, but the form doesn't send the textarea value.

I tried adding a name attribute to textarea, also a form attribute with the form id but it still doesn't send any value and I don't know why. How do I solve this problem?

```html
<form id="form-formulario_incidencia" method="POST" action="./nuevaIncidencia.php">
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="form-titulo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
   Título: 
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" id="form-titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" required="" readonly="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="form-descripcion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
   Descripción: 
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="form-descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3" required="" form="form-formulario_incidencia" disabled=""></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="form-lugar" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
   Lugar: 
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" id="form-lugar" name="lugar" class="form-control" required="" readonly="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="form-palabras_clave" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
   Palabras Clave: 
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" id="form-palabras_clave" name="palabras_clave" class="form-control" readonly="">
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="submit" value="Confirmar la inserción" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="enviarFormularioIncidencia()">
     </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

This is what `var_dump($_POST);` returns:

```
array(3) {
  ["titulo"]=>
  string(8) "Prueba 1"
  ["lugar"]=>
  string(6) "London"
  ["palabras_clave"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `textarea` element contains the `disabled` attribute. Even though it's set to an empty value, its presence alone signifies a disabled form element and the browser will not send it.

From the [HTML 5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute), on boolean attributes:

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

The same goes for the `readonly` attribute on the elements as well.